# Cannot start IOTA HUB

Tags: hub

When running iota rpc hub, I am met with the fatal error

```
E0906 15:37:44.322824 11458 beast.cc:65] [json.exception.parse_error.101] parse error at 1: syntax error - invalid literal; last read: '<'
```

I am sure that this is a fault of my own, but I have been banging my head for a while trying to figure it out. I cannot find more info on it. I will post a log including database debug below.

My main problem is: what is `beast.cc` parsing?

NOTE: I am using a remote iri node that I do not host.

The way I built IOTA hub was based on the instructions from the getting started.

**Hardware Spec**

Running on arch linux, using mariadb, signing server is on.

**Steps To Reproduce**

Start signing server, no issues.

```
Running $RPCHUB/bazel-bin/hub/hub --salt alotofcharactertorepresentmysaltbutitsnotactuallymysalt --apiAddress iotanode.us:443 --db iota --dbUser iota --dbPassword myiotapassword --monitorInterval 500 --attachmentInterval 500 --sweepInterval 500 --dbDebug where $RPCHUB is the actual path of the hub.
```

**Expected behavior**

Should run successfully.

**Actual behavior**

hub.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=6/ABRT
Errors

```
Sep 06 15:37:43 taxi systemd[1]: Started IOTA HUB.
Sep 06 15:37:43 taxi hub[11452]: MySQL debug: Executing: 'SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE'
Sep 06 15:37:43 taxi hub[11452]: MySQL debug: Executing: 'SELECT user_address.seed_uuid,user_address.address FROM user_address LIMIT 1'
Sep 06 15:37:43 taxi hub[11452]: MySQL debug: Constructing result, using handle at 0x55740aee4f30
Sep 06 15:37:43 taxi hub[11452]: MySQL debug: Accessing next row of handle at 0x55740aee4f30
Sep 06 15:37:43 taxi hub[11452]: MySQL debug: Executing: 'SELECT user_address.id,user_address.address FROM user_address WHERE (NOT EXISTS(SELECT user_address_balance.id>
Sep 06 15:37:43 taxi hub[11452]: MySQL debug: Constructing result, using handle at 0x55740af055b0
Sep 06 15:37:43 taxi hub[11452]: MySQL debug: Accessing next row of handle at 0x55740af055b0
Sep 06 15:37:43 taxi hub[11452]: MySQL debug: Accessing next row of handle at 0x55740af055b0
Sep 06 15:37:43 taxi hub[11452]: MySQL debug: Executing: 'SELECT user_address.balance FROM user_address WHERE (user_address.id=2)'
Sep 06 15:37:43 taxi hub[11452]: MySQL debug: Constructing result, using handle at 0x55740af055b0
Sep 06 15:37:43 taxi hub[11452]: MySQL debug: Accessing next row of handle at 0x55740af055b0
Sep 06 15:37:43 taxi hub[11452]: MySQL debug: Executing: 'SELECT user_address.balance FROM user_address WHERE (user_address.id=1)'
Sep 06 15:37:43 taxi hub[11452]: MySQL debug: Constructing result, using handle at 0x55740af05940
Sep 06 15:37:43 taxi hub[11452]: MySQL debug: Accessing next row of handle at 0x55740af05940
Sep 06 15:37:44 taxi hub[11452]: MySQL debug: Executing: 'SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE'
Sep 06 15:37:44 taxi hub[11452]: MySQL debug: Executing: 'SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE'
Sep 06 15:37:44 taxi hub[11452]: MySQL debug: Executing: 'SELECT user_address.id,user_address.address FROM user_address WHERE (NOT EXISTS(SELECT user_address_balance.id>
Sep 06 15:37:44 taxi hub[11452]: MySQL debug: Executing: 'SELECT sweep.id,sweep.bundle_hash,sweep.trytes,sweep.into_hub_address FROM sweep WHERE ((sweep.created_at<=TIM>
Sep 06 15:37:44 taxi hub[11452]: MySQL debug: Constructing result, using handle at MySQL debug: Constructing result, using handle at 0x7f7e3c009b50MySQL debug: Executin>
Sep 06 15:37:44 taxi hub[11452]: MySQL debug: Accessing next row of handle at 0x7f7e3c009b50
Sep 06 15:37:44 taxi hub[11452]: MySQL debug: Accessing next row of handle at 0x7f7e44009b20
Sep 06 15:37:44 taxi hub[11452]: MySQL debug: Accessing next row of handle at MySQL debug: Accessing next row of handle at 0x7f7e3c009b50
Sep 06 15:37:44 taxi hub[11452]: 0x7f7e44009b20SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE'
Sep 06 15:37:44 taxi hub[11452]: MySQL debug: Executing: 'START TRANSACTION'
Sep 06 15:37:44 taxi hub[11452]: MySQL debug: Executing: 'START TRANSACTION'
Sep 06 15:37:44 taxi hub[11452]: E0906 15:37:44.319941 11459 beast.cc:65] [json.exception.parse_error.101] parse error at 1: syntax error - invalid literal; last read: >
Sep 06 15:37:44 taxi hub[11452]: MySQL debug: Executing: 'ROLLBACK'
Sep 06 15:37:44 taxi hub[11452]: E0906 15:37:44.320693 11457 beast.cc:65] [json.exception.parse_error.101] parse error at 1: syntax error - invalid literal; last read: >
Sep 06 15:37:44 taxi hub[11452]: E0906 15:37:44.322824 11458 beast.cc:65] [json.exception.parse_error.101] parse error at 1: syntax error - invalid literal; last read: >
Sep 06 15:37:44 taxi hub[11452]: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_optional_access'
Sep 06 15:37:44 taxi hub[11452]:   what():  bad optional access
Sep 06 15:37:44 taxi hub[11452]: *** Aborted at 1536273464 (unix time) try "date -d @1536273464" if you are using GNU date ***
Sep 06 15:37:44 taxi hub[11452]: PC: @                0x0 (unknown)
Sep 06 15:37:44 taxi systemd[1]: hub.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=6/ABRT
Sep 06 15:37:44 taxi systemd[1]: hub.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
```

If anyone can help me in any way, even just getting more log output, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: The message on top is different from the actual error message. Did you manually type it or was it really a different one? Also it seems that some pager or similar is truncating long lines at column 170 with a `>`, can you try running it in a bigger tty or try if you can scroll to the right somehow?

Comment: Also, in case the answer to https://github.com/iotaledger/rpchub/issues/199 helped you, please answer your question here or delete it